# How to stop cloth-physics from catching on pointy surfaces?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm using cloth because soft-body is too slow. As a test I have a character's hand pushing against a zero-gravity cloth surface with high structural integrity, but the when the character pulls back, the drag of the cloth causes it to catch on their fingers and twists and wraps around before falling off. What setting can I modify to stop this from happening? Part of the problem is the hand pokes through the cloth and I don't know how to prevent that either. Subdividing the cloth somehow makes the problem worse.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these come with larger simulation times, try to keep the subdivision to a minimum.

1. Increase the substeps of the simulation to prevent the geometries from ever intersecting.
2. Increase the quality of the collision with the *Quality* slider.
3. Increase the (minimum) *Distance* of the collision. Note that this will also create a gap between the object. I would advise to simulate with an offset animated collider, which can be repositioned after baking.
4. Replace the animated object with **simpler geometry**. Recreate the basic shape with concave meshes, with evenly distributed triangles while trying to keep the edge angle at a minimum. Hide these helper collision for rendering.

Comment: Is there a way to use a kind of proxy mesh for calculating cloth deformations? Or would that just make it more complicated?

Comment: That's what I meant with (4). Use a proxy mesh. Concave, small angles, low poly, non-deform if possible.

Comment: @AskingRandomQuestions If an answer helped you in some way upvote it so it may help others in the future. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: I don't know yet if it helped yet. I tried a few steps and it didn't help much.